# IIS 10 PHP rewrite rule not running

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016

I'm attempting to rewrite all PHP requests to 410 Gone on IIS 10/Windows Server 2016. With this rule in place, PHP requests are returning 404 errors. If I change the pattern to "^.*.ph1", a request to /test.ph1 returns 410.

What could be catching the PHP request to return a 404 prior to URL Rewrite rules? PHP is not installed on this server.

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RequestBlockingRule1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.php" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="410" statusReason="Gone" statusDescription="Gone" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Request Filtering will catch requests before URL Rewrite rules, and sets a 404.7 response (that gets sent back to the browser as 404).